# How do I create a static permanent ifconfig alias?

Tags: network, command-line

How do I get this `ifconfig` loopback alias change to persist after a restart?

```
$ sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.16.222.111
$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 172.16.222.111 netmask 0xffff0000          ### <-- WANTED!!!
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
```

The only similar instructions I've found are for nonexistent OSX files on other *nix systems for files like `/etc/network/interfaces` or `/etc/sysconfig/networking-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can create the persistent alias in Network in System Preferences.

[image]
[image]

However, the `lo0` loopback device doesn't show up here.  For this special case, we need to utilize `launchd` to kick off a short script with the `ifconfig` command you used above.

Here is a sample .plist file, saved as `com.user.lo0-loopback.plist` (can be saved anywhere as it will be copied to the appropriate directory later).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd > 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
  <key>Label</key> 
  <string>com.user.lo0-loopback</string> 
  <key>ProgramArguments</key> 
  <array> 
    <string>/sbin/ifconfig</string> 
    <string>lo0</string> 
    <string>alias</string> 
    <string>172.16.222.111</string> 
  </array> 
  <key>RunAtLoad</key> <true/> 
  <key>Nice</key> 
  <integer>10</integer> 
  <key>KeepAlive</key> 
  <false/> 
  <key>AbandonProcessGroup</key> 
  <true/> 
  <key>StandardErrorPath</key> 
  <string>/var/log/loopback-alias.log</string> 
  <key>StandardOutPath</key> 
  <string>/var/log/loopback-alias.log</string> 
</dict> 
</plist>
```

Next, move it to the `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` directory so it's kicked off at boot (will be run as `root`) and set the correct permissions

```
$ cp com.user.lo0-loopback.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/ 

$ chmod 0644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.user.lo0-loopback.plist 
$ chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.user.lo0-loopback.plist
```

Then load it with `launchctl`

```
$ launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.user.lo0-loopback.plist
```

Reboot and your `lo0` loopback should have an alias IP assigned to it that will be persistent across reboots.