# add a permanent static route in high sierra

Tags: network, unix, router

I'm adding a route to all `192.168.1.x` ips through a gateway like so: `sudo route add 192.168.1.0/24 10.0.0.2` .  How do I add this route permanently in High Sierra?

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296647/how-do-i-create-a-static-permanent-ifconfig-alias

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest to use `networksetup` which works persistent and also in separate network locations.

First, open your terminal of choice i.e. iTerm2.app or Terminal.app

- list your network locations:

`networksetup -listlocations`

- choose your desired network location:

`sudo networksetup -switchtolocation <locationofchoice>`

- list "devices" called networkservices

`networksetup -listallnetworkservices`

- list persistent routes on "device" of choice i.e. "Ethernet"

`networksetup -getadditionalroutes Ethernet`

- add your route to "Ethernet"

`sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes Ethernet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2`

- list persistent routes on "Ethernet" again to check

`networksetup -getadditionalroutes Ethernet`

To see all commands:

`networksetup -help` or 
`networksetup -printcommands`

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: This is the correct answer... it's also permanent so it will survive after reboots.

Comment: Make note that if you want to add more than one route you have to do it in a line. For example: `sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes Ethernet 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2 10.2.0.0/16 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.2`. And if you run a command without routes than you will delete existed additional routes(`sudo networksetup -setadditionalroutes Ethernet`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I added a permanent static route:

1. Create a script somewhere.  `vi ~/path_to_script`
2. add your route like so:  `add route 192.168.1.0/24 10.0.0.2`
3. `sudo visudo`
4. on the last line write `username ALL=(ALL) /Users/username/path_to_script` (or something like that, you'll figure it out!)
5. `sudo chown root path_to_script`
6. `sudo chmod +x path_to_script`
7. `sudo chmod -w path_to_script`
8. now create a `.plist` file, make sure you've got `<ProgramArguments>` with `<string><sudo></string>`and `<string><path_to_script></string>` .
9. save that thing to `~/Library/LaunchAgents`
10. `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/path_to_plist`

Comment: do you have an example for this script and for the .plist file?

Comment: What's the purpose of running `sudo` from a LaunchAgent? This should never be necessary, just have `launchd` launch it with the correct user. This would also avoid the security risk introduced by opening `sudo` for the script.

Comment: @patix in addition to downvoting feel free to provide a helpful answer

Comment: This method fails for example when your active network connection switches between wifi & ethernet.

Comment: @Motsel good looking out.  how would you do it?

Comment: @WalrustheCat use `networksetup -setadditionalroutes` (for both Wifi and Ethernet devices), as answered by @Cellcore above. That way it always works, even after rebooting or switching between wifi & ethernet.