# How to run a one-liner shell command using launchd?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, terminal, mac, launchd

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>fooLabel</string>
        <key>Something</key>
        <string>/bin/bash foo -arg 1 -arg 2 &</string>
</dict> 
</plist>
```

The plist was added to `/Library/LaunchDaemons` so it should run at boot for all users, right? The [appropriate file permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296647/how-do-i-create-a-static-permanent-ifconfig-alias/296652#296652) were set.

The script needs to run as a background process and also requires network connectivity. How can I make sure the plist doesnt launch until internet access is established?

Comment: Join me in chat  https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat

Answer (score 3):

You want to include this check for network state:

```
<dict>
  <key>NetworkState</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Also - you probably want to pass in your program args correctly:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/binaryname</string>
    <string>arg1</string>
    <string>arg2</string>
</array>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. im still having some trouble. could you show an example of using args for the following command? `tail -n100 /var/log/foo.log | curl -s --data - http://website.com/upload/ 2>&1 >/tmp/bar`

Comment: Much easier to wrap up what you want to do into a script and call that from launchd.